# Spread authentication protocol that supports multi-factor authentication

Tags: java, authentication

Let's suppose that I have authentication infrastructure that provides multi-factor authentication. I want to create a service which will authenticate users for some clients. Clients have different web servers like Apache, jBoss, TomCat, WebLogic, IIS 7.0, and some other.

I need to insert an existing java front-end into my infrastructure based on some authentication protocol to interact with my clients' servers. The requirements are: existing solutions for clients' servers that will need minimal changes and settings at client side.

**Upd1** : Interaction between font-end and clients' servers should be secure, based on shared secret.

**Upd2** : The client's user shouldn't know anything about my service.

Please ask for more details...

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you do indeed need a SAML IDP which enforces multi factor authentication. SAML is supported across platforms (Java, Spring Security, PHP and .NET come to mind). If you're looking for a hosted solution check out our [Cloudseal](http://www.cloudseal.com) platform. If you want an open source solution you may want to look at [CAS](http://www.jasig.org/cas), although you will have to code your own integration with a multi factor authenticaton system.